# Profile Nashorn Javascript execution?

Tags: javascript, java, jprofiler, nashorn, jvmti

When using JProfiler 9.1 to profile a JVM (1.8.0_65-b17 on Mac) running Javascript code through Nashorn, it turns out that calls into `javax.script.ScriptEngine.eval()` cannot be further profiled:

[image: JProfiler Call Tree on Nashorn JS execution]

The nashorn-dev mailing list seems to say that profiling via JVMTI should be possible, though: [Nashorn and JVMTI](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/nashorn-dev/2014-October/003576.html)

Does anybody per chance have a hint on what could be the problem here?

Answer (score 2):

OK, stupid me. Just in case it may be useful to others: JProfiler's default settings for filtering Java packages did effectively exclude those that I was interested in.

Using these filter settings:

[image: Filter settings]

Allows to take a deep peek into the Nashorn:

[image: Profiling Nashorn call tree]